# Why is render :text => @object.inspect not working [debugging in rails]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I have in my controller something very straightforward:

```
def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    render :text => @group.inspect
end
```

I know that @group exists because if I send it to view (by commenting out the third line), it shows everything correctly. However, when I includethat render text line, I get simply a "#" and nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rendering correctly if you view the source of the page. The problem is that the output is something like this:

```
#<Group id: 123, ...>
```

The browser expects HTML, so when it sees the opening bracket it thinks it's an HTML tag (but it's really not valid HTML).

Instead you could try escaping the HTML first:

```
render :text => CGI.escapeHTML(@group.inspect)
```

This will replace `<` with `&lt;`, etc., properly displaying what you expect.